# Complete Graph k-Coloring Solver

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, constraint-programming

I am looking for a complete CSP solver, meaning it will always find a solution if it exists and will tell you if no solution exists. A solver that is optimized for graph coloring is preferred, but not necessary. There are many iterative algorithms/solvers out there but I require a completeness(?) for my work.

I have implemented my own solver using the Weak-Commitment Search algorithm but I'm sure there are many optimizations and thread-based features that could make for a much faster solver and allow me to increase the number of variables I can use in my simulation. I realize it's an exponentially difficult problem, but every little bit will help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has [implemented](http://code.google.com/p/exactcolors/) the branch-and-price method of [Mehrotra and Trick](http://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/trick/color.ps). I haven't used this code, but I believe that the approach is the state of the art in exact coloring.